# How can I get a OSX mountain lion installer for deployment testing?

Tags: macos, vmware, virtualization

I have a macmini which came with Mountain Lion preinstalled as from factory. I need to create a virtual machine on this macmini (OSX host/OSX guest) with the same version for end-user deployment testing. I went to the apple store to get the installer, but I can only get mavericks, and I want to test deployment on 10.8. How can I get a ML installer so I can use vmware or virtualbox to install osx in the virtual image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Developers registered with Apple's [Mac Developer Program](https://developer.apple.com/programs/mac/) can [download older editions](https://developer.apple.com/devcenter/mac/index.action#downloads) of Mac OS X for development and testing purposes.

The screenshot below shows OS X Mountain Lion is still available to developers.

[image: Mac downloads from Apple]

Comment: This won't work in Yosemite - I get the following error: http://i.stack.imgur.com/e3aab.png

Comment: @nathan-osman please can you open a new question. The problem you are seeing deserves dedicated answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can purchase Mountain Lion from the Apple Store.

- http://store.apple.com/us/product/D6377Z/A/os-x-mountain-lion

This gives you a code which lets you redeem Moutain Lion from the Mac App Store and download the installer.